# What happens when some files use the ABIEncoderV2 and some don't

Tags: solidity

The version 2 of the ABIEncoder used by solidity can be enabled with:

`pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`

What happens if I compile with truffe  a project that has some files with that pragma and some without it? Is the entire project using the new pragma or only the contracts declaring it?

What happens if I compile a solidity file without the experimental pragma, but that imports a file with the pragma?

Comment: Also interested in this. Did you ever figure it out?